# Get Data using MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Tags: vba, web-scraping

i am trying to get data using MSXML2.XMLHTTP
but it didn't work

any ideas?

```
Sub getdata

Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As String
Dim sht As Worksheet


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set sht = ActiveSheet


    On Error Resume Next
    website = "https://shopee.co.id/AFI-EC-Tshirt-Yumia-(LD-90-P-57)-i.10221730.5568491283"
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

   request.Open "GET", website, False
   request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
   request.send
   response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
   html.DocumentElement.innerHTML = response

    
    price = html.querySelector("div.AJyN7v")(0).innerText
    
    Debug.Print price
    
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True``
End Sub
```

I have done many ways but still not working ,
hope someone can help me

Comment: "didn't work" is not a useful description of what happens when you run your code. Do you get an error?  If Yes what error and which line.  Please review [ask] and consider improving your post with some additional details.

Comment: no error message

Comment: can you try running my code?
I want to get the Price

Comment: Try without `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: there is an error message
Object variable or With block variable not set

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much everything on that page requires javascript to load. Javascript doesn't run with xmlhttp request to landing page so price never gets retrieved..

The price is being retrieved dynamically from an additional API call returning json.

If you examine the url you will have the following:

`https://shopee.co.id/AFI-EC-Tshirt-Yumia-(LD-90-P-57)-i.10221730.5568491283`

The last set of consecutive numbers is the product id i.e. `5568491283`.

If you open the network tab of dev tools <kbd>F12</kbd>, and press F5 to refresh the web traffic that updates the page, then check on the xhr only traffic, then input your product id into the search box, the first result retrieved is the xhr which is returning the price:

`https://shopee.co.id/api/v2/item/get?itemid=5568491283&shopid=10221730`

The response is json so you will need a json parser to extract the result (or use regex on string - less preferable)

[image]

In the headers sub-tab you can view info about the xhr request made.

Check the terms and conditions to see if scraping allowed and also whether there is an public API for retrieving this data.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborative visual. It will immensely help future readers to understand what really goes on in the background.

Comment: how to parser json ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json+user%3A9912714+is%3Aanswer , https://stackoverflow.com/a/66146810