# Json scraping options VBA

Tags: json, vba, web-scraping

i am trying to scrape date from https://www.jjfox.co.uk/aj-fernandez-bellas-artes-maduro.html using Json parser with the following code. the code does not however render any results. this is partially related to a question asked and answered earlier in here, however teh code has stoped working: [Scraping website data with options in combo box VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66145742/scraping-website-data-with-options-in-combo-box-vba/66146810?noredirect=1#comment116960299_66146810)

```
    Option Explicit

Sub collectData()

Dim I As Integer
Dim bb As String
Dim a(1 To 1) As String

a(1) = "https://www.jjfox.co.uk/cigars/view-all.html?product_list_limit=all&product_list_order=name"
'a(2) = "https://www.jjfox.co.uk/best-sellers/show/all.html"
'a(3) = "https://www.jjfox.co.uk/new-arrivals/show/all.html"
'a(4) = "https://www.jjfox.co.uk/cigar-accessories/show/all.html"
'a(5) = "https://www.jjfox.co.uk/cigar-gifts/show/all.html"


For I = 1 To UBound(a)

    bb = texter(a(I))
    
Next I


    
    
End Sub


Public Function texter(ntx As String)

Dim cnt As Integer
Dim counter1 As Integer

Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
Dim oElement As Object
Dim elm As Object

Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    .Open "GET", ntx, False
    .send
    oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With


Dim innerlink As String
counter1 = cnt

Set oElement = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("products wrapper grid products-grid")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each elm In oElement
    'If elm.className = "products-grid products-grid--max-3-col" Then
    
    
    innerlink = elm.href
    Debug.Print elm.href
   GetCigarData (innerlink)
   
    'End If
Next

End Function

Public Sub GetCigarData(hh As String)
    '<  VBE > Tools > References:
    'Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    'Microsoft HTML Object Library
    'Microsoft XML Library
    
    
    
    Dim json As Object, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, ws As Worksheet
    Dim nme As Variant
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JJFox")
    ws.Activate
    Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Dim lastrow As Double
    Dim cnt As Double
    
Cells(1, 1).Select
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
cnt = lastrow + 1

Dim nump As Long
    
    nme = hh
    
    If hh <> "" Then
    
    If InStr(1, hh, "sampl", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, hh, "best-of", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, hh, "mini", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, hh, "leather-case", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, hh, "club", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, hh, "box", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, hh, "single", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
    
        With xhr
            .Open "GET", hh, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            .send
             html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
    
        On Error Resume Next
        
         Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(html.querySelector(".fieldset [type='text/x-magento-init']").innerHTML)("#product_addtocart_form")("configurable")("spConfig")
          
         Dim prices As Scripting.dictionary, options As Scripting.dictionary, optionsCollection As Collection
         
         Set prices = json("optionPrices")
         Set options = json("attributes")
         Set optionsCollection = options(options.Keys(0))("options")
         

        
         Dim results() As Variant, headers() As Variant, I As Long, name As String
         ReDim results(1 To optionsCollection.Count, 1 To 7)
         
         name = html.querySelector(".base").innerText
         
         Debug.Print name
         
        For I = 1 To optionsCollection.Count
              results(I, 1) = name
              results(I, 2) = optionsCollection.Item(I)("label")
              results(I, 3) = prices(prices.Keys(I - 1))("finalPrice")("amount")
              results(I, 4) = "JJFox"
              results(I, 5) = Now()
              results(I, 6) = ""
              results(I, 7) = nme
         Next
         
         'headers = Array("Name", "Size", "Price")
         
         With ws
             '.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
             .Cells(cnt, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
         End With
 
   End If
   End If
   
   Cells(lastrow, 7).Select
   Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(lastrow, 7), Cells(cnt, 7))
End Sub
```

The part that does not work is this, as it returns Nothing every time and i have no idea why:

```
         Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(html.querySelector(".fieldset [type='text/x-magento-init']").innerHTML)("#product_addtocart_form")("configurable")("spConfig")

     Dim prices As Scripting.dictionary, options As Scripting.dictionary, optionsCollection As Collection

     Set prices = json("optionPrices")
     Set options = json("attributes")
     Set optionsCollection = options(options.Keys(0))("options")
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with *"the code has stopped working"*? What happens? Did it used to work? What changed? Have you debugged it? Do you get an error message? Which? Also (especially if you post such an amount of code), it helps if you indent your code properly. And variable names like `nump`, `nme` and `hh` doesn't mean anything - give them names that are more meaningfull.

Comment: Thank you @FunThomas. Yes it did use to work, but not sure what changed. I am guessing the website code. nump - please ignore, it does not appear anywhere. 'nme' is the text representation of string, link to the webpage and "hh" is just the reference to a string passed from innerlink in the function that accesses the search data table.

Comment: You missunderstood: Don't start to explain the variables. Make it a habit to give variables a name that does not need to be explained.